# GoogleSheets - bringing back last "n" characters that are uppercase only

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data that brings back a name plus the ticker code.  I need to extract the ticker code only into google sheets.

using: =IMPORTXML("https://www.coingecko.com/?page=5","//tr") I bring back 100 coins but the first column is for example
Dogecoin9DOGE
or
Ethereum2ETH
or
Ethereum ClassicETC

I would like to create a column that simply has DOGE or ETH or ETC, anyone know of a way to manipulate the 1st column to get to that?
Thanks

the webpage looks like it is 2 separate columns but the extract does not work that way.  I was trying to think of a way to count the uppercase values and then maybe use a RIGHT(len(uppercasevalues)) but not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use REGEXEXTRACT.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[A-Z]+$")
```